# loading a sparse matrix saved with np.save

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I saved a scipy csr matrix using `np.save('X', X)`.  When I load it with `np.load('X.npy')`, I get this signiture:

`array(<240760x110493 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20618831 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)`

However, I cannot access this data using indexes (such as `X[0,0]` or `X[:10,:10] or X[0]` all give error `IndexError: too many indices for array`) and calling `.shape` returns `()`.

Is there a way to access this data, or is it corrupt now?

## Edit.

Since there are 3 options to save/load a matrix I ran a speed comparison to see which works the best for my sparse matrix:

### Writing a sparse matrix:

```
%timeit -n1 scipy.io.savemat('tt', {'t': X})
1 loops, best of 3: 66.3 ms per loop

timeit -n1 scipy.io.mmwrite('tt_mm', X)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.55 s per loop

timeit -n1 np.save('tt_np', X)
1 loops, best of 3: 188 ms per loop
```

### Reading a sparse matrix:

```
timeit -n1 scipy.io.loadmat('tt')
1 loops, best of 3: 9.78 ms per loop

%timeit -n1 scipy.io.mmread('tt_mm')
1 loops, best of 3: 5.72 s per loop

%timeit -n1 np.load('tt_np.npy')
1 loops, best of 3: 150 ms per loop
```

The results are that `mmread/mmwrite` are incredibly low (~100s times slower), and `savemat/loadmat` is 3-10 times faster than `save/load`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's pay attention to all the clues in the print

```
array(<240760x110493 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
     with 20618831 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

Outermost:

```
array(....,dtype=object)
```

A sparse matrix is not a regular array; to `np.save`, it is just an Python object.  So it wrapped it in a `dtype=object` and saved that. It is a 0d array (hence the `()` shape), so all the indexing attempts fail.  Try instead

```
M=arr.item() # or
M=arr[()]
```

Now `M` should display as:

```
sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
     with 20618831 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format
```

with attributes like `M.shape`.  `M.A` will display the dense form, to it's too large to do that usefully.

Comment: Thanks!  that worked.  I never thought of a a python object as a 0-d array.

Comment: Yes, 0d arrays are a bit of stretch for all of us.  Good thing they didn't try to implement negative dimensions. :)

Comment: `scipy.io.savemat/loadmat` know how to save and load sparse matrices - in a MATLAB compatible format.

Comment: I tried `scipy.io.mmread/mmload` and it was really slow compared to `np.read/write`.  Is `scipy.io.savemat/loadmat` faster than `scipy.io.mmread/mmwrite`?

Comment: I've never used the `mmread` ones; and haven't timed the `savemat`.  I can imagine saving a `csr` matrix with `savez`, saving 3 arrays, (the `data`, `indices`, `indptr` attributes) plus shape information (dtype is contained in `data`).  That may be the fastest and most compact method, but I don't know if anyone has implemented it.